# Number of registries and devices we can create on Google IoT Core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

Question is simple:

- How many devices can we create in registry ?
- How many registries can we have ?

Is there any limitation ?

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas#project_device_and_telemetry_limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates will be published to the [Google Cloud IoT Quotas and Limits page](https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas).

You can have an unlimited number of devices per registry but Google will default your registry to 100,000.

You are limited to 100 registries per Google Cloud Project.